# ERROR : could not set the configuration for CRTC 64 any idea? 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, hdmi

I have been trying to connect the Hdmi to my laptop so i watch movies on the LED but whenever i connect it, I only get audio but not the video and only the wallpaper appears on the LED,when i disconnect it i get the error could not set the configuration for CRTC 64. My graphics card is GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2. How do I resolve this issue?